# Space for fractional partial differential equation

Tags: fractional-sobolev-spaces

I have to study the following spatial fractional differential equation
$$
\dfrac{\partial x(z,\,t)}{\partial t}=\dfrac{\partial ^\alpha x(z,\,t)}{\partial z^\alpha}
$$
with $1\leq \alpha<2$ and $0<z<l$.

I ask how to select the appropriate functional space for $x(z,\,t)$ ? Is $L^2(z,\,t)$ a best choice?

Comment: You might want to say which fractional derivative you have opted to use.

Comment: I use the Caputo definition for the derivative but a look for the right space (Sobolev, Banach,...)